# Possessive pronoun: Why "mein Auto", not "meinen Auto"?

Tags: german-to-english

Ich wasche *mein* Auto

Ich sehe *meine* Kinder

I get that *meine* is used for plural accusative form

But why is *mein* correct for first sentence? Shouldn't it be *meinen* instead?

I am learning using table in 
https://www.deutsch-lernen.com/learn-german-online/beginners/lesson_6.php

I am not getting the difference between Possessivpronomen I and Possessivpronomen II

Please help.

Comment: One should have to register to get access to the hyperlinked table - for me too inconvenient .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a table with the correct forms of *mein*:

(Note that *Auto* is not male, not female, but neuter: *das Auto*)

[image: Konjugationstabelle "mein"]

You find similar tables for *dein*, *sein*, *euer* etc. here: 
http://longua.org/possessivartikel-ubersicht.php

Comment: Thank you.
If I decide to use 'Dein' or 'unser' instead, I would just plug in those words instead of mein right?

Comment: @KevinEleven yes, that is correct. If I'm not mistaken, the suffix (e.g. nothing, "-e", "-er", "-en", ...) after the word root (e.g. "mein") is the same for all possessive pronouns (mein, dein, sein/ihr, unser, euer, ihr).

Comment: @PixleMaster: I think it is different with _euer_. Whenever completed by an ending it must be 'eur', only without termination it is 'euer'. In fact, you can say 'euere', 'eueren' and so on, but in my area (Ruhrgebiet) nobody will talk this way, it will always be 'eure', 'euren' ...

Comment: @RalfJoerres I would say "eure" as well, but "euere" is also correct. See also https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/euer_Anrede_wessen

Comment: I never heard of `euere` and despite it being mentioned in Duden, I think the majority of people will deem it wrong.

Answer (score 3):

The reason why "mein" is correct in your example is the 'gender' of the word "Auto". More specifically, "mein" is for words that have would have the "das" article, while "meine" is female and used for words that would have the "die" article. For words with the male "der" article, "meinen" would be used here.

The same is basically true in the plural form, except words in the plural form usually use the female article "die" (in fact, I can't think of an example where that's not the case).

More examples:

- Ich wasche mein T-Shirt (***das*** T-Shirt)
- Ich putze mein Haus (***das*** Haus)
- Ich wasche mein Trinkglas (***das*** Glas)
- Ich sehe mein Kind (***das*** Kind)
- Ich sehe mein**e** Kinder (***die*** Kinder, plural)
- Ich sehe mein**e** Tochter (***die*** Tochter)
- Ich wasche mein**e** Hose (***die*** Hose)
- Ich wasche mein**e** Socken (***die*** Socken, plural)
- Ich wasche mein**e** Mütze (***die*** Mütze)
- Ich putze mein**e** Wohnung (***die*** Wohnung)
- Ich putze mein**en** Herd (***der*** Herd)
- Ich putze mein**en** XBox-Controller (***der*** Controller)
- Ich sehe mein**en** Sohn (***der*** Sohn)
- Ich sehe mein**en** Hund (***der*** Hund)
- Ich wasche mein**en** Pfannenwender (***der*** Pfannenwender)

Comment: Thank you. But in 'Wir sehen schon unser Haus'
'unser' is used instead of 'mein'

I am assuming this is because 'Wir' is used in the sentence, but does that mean I would only use mein, meinem, meines, meinen ... etc only when I use 'ich'?

In other words, in the link I posted, would I use table 2 and table 3 only when using ich?

Comment: It doesn't matter, if it is "wir sehen..." or "ich sehe...": If the house is considered belonging to me directly and nobody else, then it is "mein Haus". If it is considered belonging to the whole family (more common), then it is "unser Haus". So all these cases are possible and valid (depending on context): `Ich sehe unser Haus`, `Ich sehe mein Haus`, `Wir sehen unser Haus`, `Wir sehen mein Haus`

Comment: @KevinEleven as Torsten explained, "mein" (or "dein", "sein", "ihr", "unser", "euer", "ihr") are used to express possession of something. The english equivalents are "my", "your", "his", "her", "our", "your" and "their". The difference is that in german, there are different articles ("der", "die", "das"), which lead to the possessive pronoun being conjugated.